# Is there an easy function from a pair of 32-bit ints to a single 64-bit int that preserves rotational order?

Tags: algorithm, math

This is a question that came up in the context of sorting points with integer coordinates into clockwise order, but this question is not about how to do that sorting.

This question is about the observation that 2-d vectors have a natural cyclic ordering.  Unsigned integers with usual overflow behavior (or signed integers using twos-complement) also have a natural cyclic ordering.  Can you easily map from the first ordering to the second?

So, the exact question is whether there is a map from pairs of twos-complement signed 32-bit integers to unsigned (or twos-complement signed) 64-bit integers such that any list of vectors that is in clockwise order maps to integers that are in decreasing (modulo overflow) order?

Some technical cases that people will likely ask about:

- Yes, vectors that are multiples of each other should map to the same thing
- No, I don't care which vector (if any) maps to 0
- No, the images of antipodal vectors don't have to differ by 2^63 (although that *is* a nice-to-have)

The obvious answer is that since there are only around 0.6*2^64 distinct slopes, the answer is yes, such a map exists, but I'm looking for one that is easily computable.  I understand that "easily" is subjective, but I'm really looking for something reasonably efficient and not terrible to implement.  So, in particular, no counting every lattice point between the ray and the positive x-axis (unless you know a clever way to do that without enumerating them all).

An important thing to note is that it can be done by mapping to 6*5*-bit integers.  Simply project the vector out to where it hits the box bounded by [x,y=+/-2^62](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/latex-on-stack-overflow) and round toward negative infinity.  You need 63 bits to represent that integer and two more to encode which side of the box you hit.  The implementation needs a little care to make sure you don't overflow, but only has one branch and two divides and is otherwise quite cheap.  It doesn't work if you project out to 2^61 because you don't get enough resolution to separate some slopes.

Also, before you suggest "just use atan2", compute `atan2(1073741821,2147483643)` and `atan2(1073741820,2147483641)`

EDIT: Expansion on the "atan2" comment:

Given two values x_1 and x_2 that are coprime and just less than 2^31 (I used 2^31-5 and 2^31-7 in my example), we can use the extended Euclidean algorithm to find y_1 and y_2 such that y_1/x_1-y_2/x_2 = 1/(x_1*x_2) ~= 2^-62.  Since the derivative of arctan is bounded by 1, the difference of the outputs of atan2 on these values is not going to be bigger than that.  So, there are *lots* of pairs of vectors that won't be distinguishable by atan2 as vanilla IEEE 754 doubles.

*If* you have 80-bit extended registers *and* you are sure you can retain residency in those registers throughout the computation (and don't get kicked out by a context switch or just plain running out of extended registers), then you're fine.  But, I really don't like the correctness of my code relying on staying resident in extended registers.

Comment: What is "clockwise order" in this context? Would bit-wise interleaving of the two 32-bit entities into a 64-bit entity serve your purposes, e.g. `pdep (x, 0x5555555555555555) | pdep (y, 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa)`?

Comment: Could you explain the significance of the comment about `atan2()`? Using 64-bit IEEE-754 double precision, I get `atan2 (1073741821,2147483643)` = `0x1.dac67052e881cp-2` and `atan2 (1073741820,2147483642)` = `0x1.dac6704fb54e9p-2`. These two values are easily distinguished even assuming an error of a couple of ulps. There are probably vectors whose respective `atan2` is much closer than this, but I assume the examples were picked for a reason.

Comment: Is there anything in the Wikipedia article on [Geohash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) that comes close to the intended use case?

Comment: @njuffa.  Yep, I swapped the second values.  Fixed.

Comment: Re: clockwise order.  A pair of integers are, respectively, the x and y coordinates of a 2-dimensional vector.  That vector has a direction.  If we represent that vector in polar form, "clockwise" means "in the direction of decreasing angle/argument".  There are lots of different ways to construct a 64-bit int out of two 32-bit ints (interleaving, geohashing, simple concatenation, etc.), but I'm looking for something that specifically preserves the cyclic order.

Comment: Unfortunately `atan2` is going to be useless, because it takes `double` parameters and those only have 53 bits of precision.

Comment: @AubreydaCunha This could be on topic on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/), too, though I don't suppose the index of a fraction into the [Farey sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence#Sequence_length_and_index_of_a_fraction) counts as "*easily computable*".

Comment: @MarkRansom The inputs here are two signed 32-bit integers, each of which is easily represented exactly in a `double`. The output of `atan2` is a 64-bit datum. While `atan2` will not fully utilize all of those 64 bits, it is going to use more than 53 bits (sign bit plus 52 stored significand bits), because the exponent bits will also be *partially* utilized. So the chance of collisions should be low, and *may* be negligible for practical use cases (depends on the distribution of vectors).

Comment: Points on a circle or vectors do not have any natural rotational ordering because you can go from any one to any other one by counterclockwise rotation. Angles modulo 2\*pi measured from some particular vector do have an order, but why would you want those, and what is the significance of that special vector? Perhaps there's an XY problem hiding in there.

Comment: @MarkRansom you can use `atan2l` if `long double` has 64 bits of precision or more (which is the case on x86 where it's often 80-bit extended precision with 64 bits of significand)

Comment: Another comment about `atan2` is that you don't really gain anything compared to just using the slope directly - in fact, you lose some precision for angles closer to odd multiples of 45 degrees, because there are more distinct angles in that part of the range due to the domain being a square rather than a disc.

Comment: see the difference between `atan2(1073741821,2147483643)` and `atan2(1073741820,2147483641)` in `long double`: https://godbolt.org/z/WKaoxn1fs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one possible approach, inspired by a comment in your question. (For the tl;dr version, skip down to the definition of `point_to_line` at the bottom of this answer: that gives a mapping for the first quadrant only. Extension to the whole plane is left as a not-too-difficult exercise.)

Your question says:

> in particular, no counting every lattice point between the ray and the positive x-axis (unless you know a clever way to do that without enumerating them all).

There *is* an algorithm to do that counting without enumerating the points; its efficiency is akin to that of the Euclidean algorithm for finding greatest common divisors. I'm not sure to what extent it counts as either "easily computable" or "clever".

Suppose that we're given a point `(p, q)` with integer coordinates and both `p` and `q` positive (so that the point lies in the first quadrant). We might as well also assume that `q < p`, so that the point `(p, q)` lies between the x-axis `y = 0` and the diagonal line `y = x`: if we can solve the problem for the half of the first quadrant that lies below the diagonal, we can make use of symmetry to solve it generally.

Write `M` for the bound on the size of `p` and `q`, so that in your example we want `M = 2^31`.

Then the number of lattice points strictly inside the triangle bounded by:

- the x-axis `y = 0`
- the ray `y = (q/p)x` that starts at the origin and passes through `(p, q)`, and
- the vertical line `x = M`

is the sum as `x` ranges over integers in `(0, M)` of `⌈qx/p⌉ - 1`.

For convenience, I'll drop the `-1` and include `0` in the range of the sum; both those changes are trivial to compensate for. And now the core functionality we need is the ability to evaluate the sum of `⌈qx/p⌉` as `x` ranges over the integers in an interval `[0, M)`. While we're at it, we might also want to be able to compute a closely-related sum: the sum of `⌊qx/p⌋` over that same range of `x` (and it'll turn out that it makes sense to evaluate both of these together).

For testing purposes, here are slow, naive-but-obviously-correct versions of the functions we're interested in, here written in Python:

```py
def floor_sum_slow(p, q, M):
    """
    Sum of floor(q * x / p) for 0 <= x < M.

    Assumes p positive, q and M nonnegative.
    """
    return sum(q * x // p for x in range(M))


def ceil_sum_slow(p, q, M):
    """
    Sum of ceil(q * x / p) for 0 <= x < M.

    Assumes p positive, q and M nonnegative.
    """
    return sum((q * x + p - 1) // p for x in range(M))
```

And an example use:

```py
>>> floor_sum_slow(51, 43, 2**28)  # takes several seconds to complete
30377220771239253
>>> ceil_sum_slow(140552068, 161600507, 2**28)
41424305916577422
```

These sums can be evaluated much faster. The first key observation is that if `q >= p`, then we can apply the Euclidean "division algorithm" and write `q = ap + r` for some integers `a` and `r`. The sum then simplifies: the `ap` part contributes a factor of `a * M * (M - 1) // 2`, and we're reduced from computing `floor_sum(p, q, M)` to computing `floor_sum(p, r, M)`. Similarly, the computation of `ceil_sum(p, q, M)` reduces to the computation of `ceil_sum(p, q % p, M)`.

The second key observation is that we can express `floor_sum(p, q, M)` in terms of `ceil_sum(q, p, N)`, where `N` is the ceiling of `(q/p)M`. To do this, we consider the rectangle `[0, M) x (0, (q/p)M)`, and divide that rectangle into two triangles using the line `y = (q/p)x`. The number of lattice points within the rectangle that lie on or below the line is `floor_sum(p, q, M)`, while the number of lattice points within the rectangle that lie above the line is `ceil_sum(q, p, N)`. Since the total number of lattice points in the rectangle is `(N - 1)M`, we can deduce the value of `floor_sum(p, q, M)` from that of `ceil_sum(q, p, N)`, and vice versa.

Combining those two ideas, and working through the details, we end up with a pair of mutually recursive functions that look like this:

```py
def floor_sum(p, q, M):
    """
    Sum of floor(q * x / p) for 0 <= x < M.

    Assumes p positive, q and M nonnegative.
    """
    a = q // p
    r = q % p
    if r == 0:
        return a * M * (M - 1) // 2
    else:
        N = (M * r + p - 1) // p
        return a * M * (M - 1) // 2 + (N - 1) * M - ceil_sum(r, p, N)


def ceil_sum(p, q, M):
    """
    Sum of ceil(q * x / p) for 0 <= x < M.

    Assumes p positive, q and M nonnegative.
    """
    a = q // p
    r = q % p
    if r == 0:
        return a * M * (M - 1) // 2
    else:
        N = (M * r + p - 1) // p
        return a * M * (M - 1) // 2 + N * (M - 1) - floor_sum(r, p, N)
```

Performing the same calculation as before, we get exactly the same results, but this time the result is instant:

```py
>>> floor_sum(51, 43, 2**28)
30377220771239253
>>> ceil_sum(140552068, 161600507, 2**28)
41424305916577422
```

A bit of experimentation should convince you that the `floor_sum` and `floor_sum_slow` functions give the same result in all cases, and similarly for `ceil_sum` and `ceil_sum_slow`.

Here's a function that uses `floor_sum` and `ceil_sum` to give an appropriate mapping for the first quadrant. I failed to resist the temptation to make it a full bijection, enumerating points in the order that they appear on each ray, but you can fix that by simply replacing the `+ gcd(p, q)` term with `+ 1` in both branches.

```py
from math import gcd

def point_to_line(p, q, M):
    """
    Bijection from [0, M) x [0, M) to [0, M^2), preserving
    the 'angle' ordering.
    """
    if p == q == 0:
        return 0
    elif q <= p:
        return ceil_sum(p, q, M) + gcd(p, q)
    else:
        return M * (M - 1) - floor_sum(q, p, M) + gcd(p, q)
```

Extending to the whole plane should be straightforward, though just a little bit messy due to the asymmetry between the negative range and the positive range in the two's complement representation.

Here's a visual demonstration for the case `M = 7`, printed using this code:

```py
M = 7
for q in reversed(range(M)):
    for p in range(M):
        print(" {:02d}".format(point_to_line(p, q, M)), end="")
    print()
```

Results:

```py
 48 42 39 36 32 28 27
 47 41 37 33 29 26 21
 46 40 35 30 25 20 18
 45 38 31 24 19 16 15
 44 34 23 17 14 12 11
 43 22 13 10 09 08 07
 00 01 02 03 04 05 06
```

Comment: Why do you describe this as only a partial answer? It seems like it's the kind of underlying algorithm OP asked for. Am I missing something?

Comment: @גלגלעד ברקן : Good point - before recent edits it _was_ only a partial answer. It's still only partial in that there isn't code for the full case that the OP asked for.

Comment: I was pretty sure there was an EA-like algorithm to do this counting somewhat efficiently.  I was really hoping for something that wouldn't take 40+ divisions in the worst case, but it sounds like this is probably about as good as it gets. (and yes, _technically_ the full bijection doesn't fit the criterion that the output should be fixed along rays, but it's a nice touch and there are instructions for removing that feature)

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't meet your requirement for an "easy" function, nor for a "reasonably efficient" one. But in principle it would work, and it might give some idea of how difficult the problem is. To keep things simple, let's consider just the case where 0 < y ≤ x, because the full problem can be solved by splitting the full 2D plane into eight octants and mapping each to its own range of integers in essentially the same way.

A point (x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>) is "anticlockwise" of (x<sub>2</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>) if and only if the slope y<sub>1</sub>/x<sub>1</sub> is greater than the slope y<sub>2</sub>/x<sub>2</sub>. To map the slopes to integers in an order-preserving way, we can consider the sequence of all distinct fractions whose numerators and denominators are within range (i.e. up to 2<sup>31</sup>), in ascending numerical order. Note that each fraction's numerical value is between 0 and 1 since we are just considering one octant of the plane.

This sequence of fractions is finite, so each fraction has an index at which it occurs in the sequence; so to map a point (x, y) to an integer, first reduce the fraction y/x to its simplest form (e.g. using [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) to find the GCD to divide by), then compute that fraction's index in the sequence.

It turns out this sequence is called a [Farey sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence); specifically, it's the Farey sequence of order 2<sup>31</sup>. Unfortunately, computing the index of a given fraction in this sequence turns out to be neither easy nor reasonably efficient. According to the paper 
[*Computing Order Statistics in the Farey Sequence*](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-24847-7_27) by Corina E. Pǎtraşcu and Mihai Pǎtraşcu, there is a somewhat complicated algorithm to compute the rank (i.e. index) of a fraction in O(n) time, where n in your case is 2<sup>31</sup>, and there is unlikely to be an algorithm in time polynomial in log n because the algorithm can be used to factorise integers.

All of that said, there might be a much easier solution to your problem, because I've started from the assumption of wanting to map these fractions to integers as densely as possible (i.e. no "unused" integers in the target range), whereas in your question you wrote that the number of distinct fractions is about 60% of the available range of size 2<sup>64</sup>. Intuitively, that amount of leeway doesn't seem like a lot to me, so I think the problem is probably quite difficult and you may need to settle for a solution that uses a larger output range, or a smaller input range. At the very least, by writing this answer I might save somebody else the effort of investigating whether this approach is feasible.

Comment: Why is the order 2^32 if we're only considering one octant? Wouldn't it be 2^32 / 8?

Comment: @גלעדברקן It's 2^31 because that's the maximum value of a signed 32-bit integer; I wrote that while drafting the answer and I don't know why I then wrote 32 instead. The octants are like the region 0 < y <= x, but other than that, x and y can take values in the full range. "Octant" means a sector spanning an angle of 45 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Just some random ideas / observations:

(**edit**: added two more and marked the first one as wrong as pointed out in the comments)

- Divide into 16 22.5° segments instead of 8 45° segments

  If I understand the problem correctly, the lines spread out "more" towards 45°, "wasting" resolution that you need for smaller angles. (**Incorrect, see below**)
- In the mapping to 62 bit integers, there must be gaps. Identify enough low density areas to map down to 61 bits? Perhaps plot for a smaller problem to potentially see a pattern?
- As the range for x and y is limited, for a given x0, all (legal) x < x0 with y > q must have a smaller angle. Could this help to break down the problem in some way? Perhaps cutting a triangle where points can easily be enumerated out of the problem for each quadrant?

Comment: I can see how to use octants using signs a magnitudes: How do you distinguish/map "half octants"?

Comment: Are you thinking of the projection to lines "x,y=+/-2^62"? If so, I don't think this helps: to a first order approximation, that projection is uniform with respect to point density. (For example, the number of points projected to x = 2^62, 0 < y < 2^61 is roughly the same as the number of points projected to x = 2^62, 2^61 < y < 2^62: both counts are approximately equal to the areas of the projected triangles, and those two triangles have the same area.) If you're thinking of projecting to the circle (in effect, using atan2), then there is indeed a non-uniform density problem to deal with.

Comment: @MarkDickinson yeah, sorry, it looks like I fell victim to my combination of bad sampling and drawing skills... 